# using latin1 encoding in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, encoding, latin1

I am trying to setup my rails app to use latin1 encoding using the following database.yml

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
database: pana_development
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
encoding: latin1
```

When running `rake db:create` I get the following error:

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"pana_development",    "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "encoding"=>"latin1"}
PG::Error: ERROR:  encoding LATIN1 does not match locale en_US.UTF-8
DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding UTF8.
```

What do I need to do in order to setup rails using latin1 encoding in a postgresql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to supply the program versions.
Next, you need to understand that the default locale setting `LC_CTYPE` is determined at **cluster creation time**. [I quote the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/locale.html):

> Some locale categories must have their values fixed when the database
>   is created. You can use different settings for different databases,
>   but once a database is created, you cannot change them for that
>   database anymore. `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` are these categories. They
>   affect the sort order of indexes, so they must be kept fixed, or
>   indexes on text columns would become corrupt. (But you can alleviate
>   this restriction using collations, as discussed in Section 22.2.) The
>   default values for these categories are determined when initdb is run,
>   and those values are used when new databases are created, unless
>   specified otherwise in the `CREATE DATABASE` command.

You can easily solve this with [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createdatabase.html) building on the `template0` template database, which has no pre-determined objects in it.

```
CREATE DATABASE pana_development ENCODING 'LATIN1' TEMPLATE template0;
```

In Ruby, you can just supply a "template" parameter:

```
template: template0
```

Compare this closely related answer:
[rake db:create encoding error with postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821238/rake-dbcreate-encoding-error-with-postgresql/7529711#7529711)

For repeated use you should prepare a database like outlined above, put everything in it that you want in future databases and use this one as template. *Any* database can be used as template.

Or you create a new database cluster with matching `LC_TYPE` and take it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried runnig that psql command but it gives me the same error. I checked and I have no template0 db.

Comment: @Baconator507: Unless you are using a custom package or have tampered with the system you should have a template0 database. It's created by default. Try `\l` in psql. Either way, please supply your version of Postgres *in your question* before asking anything else.

Comment: @Erin, you are correct, I DO have the template0. However, I noticed that it is also on en_US.UTF-8.

Comment: @Baconator507: That is not a problem. Read the manual. I supplied deep links.

Comment: @Erin: It looks like I need to create a new cluster that uses LATIN1, is this what you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

There is a script which I have found in Gist which worked like a charm

```
sudo su postgres

psql

update pg_database set datistemplate=false where datname='template1';
drop database Template1;
create database template1 with owner=postgres encoding='UTF-8'
  lc_collate='en_US.utf8' lc_ctype='en_US.utf8' template template0;

update pg_database set datistemplate=true where datname='template1';
```

You can get the original source [here](https://gist.github.com/turboladen/6790847)

Comment: doesn’t work for me.  results in 

postgres=# create database template1 with owner=postgres encoding='UTF-8' lc_collate='en_US.utf8' lc_ctype='en_US.utf8' template template0;
ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en_US.utf8"

and now my Template1 database is dropped.